# Must declare the scalar variable in sqlConnection Execute

Tags: c#, sql

I looked at similar questions but I still couldn't figure out why it doesn't work...

I had this old code that worked like a charm:

```
    private void RegUser(DateTime firstActivity)
        {
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
                {

                    var userSidId = ActiveUsers.GetUserSerial();
                    var accountType = ActiveUsers.Value;
                        conn.Execute(@"
UPDATE TableUser SET
    AccountType=@AccountType,
    FirstActivity=@FirstActivity,
    WHERE SidID=@SidID
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
   INSERT INTO TableUser (SidID, AccountType, FirstActivity) VALUES (@SidID, @AccountType, @FirstActivity)
",
                            new {SidID = userSidId, AccountType = (int) accountType, FirstActivity = firstActivity});
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

A newer version on table TableUser can have another column (LastAccountType) and because I couldn't know on what version I'm running I added a dynamic sql to handle:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
                {

                    var userSidId = ActiveUsers.GetUserSerial();
                    var accountType = ActiveUsers.Value;
                        conn.Execute(@"
DECLARE @SQL AS VARCHAR(MAX)

UPDATE TableUser SET
    AccountType=@AccountType,
    FirstActivity=@FirstActivity,
    WHERE SidID=@SidID
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    IF COL_LENGTH('dbo.TableUser', 'LastAccountType') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN

    SET @SQL = 
    'INSERT dbo.TableUser
            ( SidID,
              AccountType,
              FirstActivity,
              LastAccountType
            )
    VALUES
            ( ' + CAST(@SidID AS nvarchar(12)) + ',
              ' + cast (@AccountType AS NVARCHAR(8)) + ',
              ''' + CONVERT (NVARCHAR, @FirstActivity, 126) + ''',
              0
            )'
    END ELSE
    BEGIN
     SET @SQL = 
    'INSERT INTO TableUser (SidID, AccountType, FirstActivity) VALUES (' + CAST(@SidID AS nvarchar(12)) + ', ' + cast (@AccountType AS NVARCHAR(8)) + ', ''' + CONVERT (NVARCHAR, @FirstActivity, 126) + ''')'
    END
EXEC(@SQL)
",
                            new {SidID = userSidId, AccountType = (int) accountType, FirstActivity = firstActivity});
                    }
                }
```

But I keep getting this "Must declare the scalar variable @SidID", why does it stop recognize it now?

Thank you

Comment: I see dynamic queries with a side helping of SQL injection.

Comment: OP, be aware that building your query like this opens you up to SQL injection. For example: a FirstActivity of `'); DROP TABLE TableUser; -- `

Answer (score -1):

Your declaration is 'userSidId', whereas you are referencing @SidID. I see no evidence of your delcaration of 'SidID'

Comment: I may be mistaken but I think the declaration is at:
new {SidID = userSidId, AccountType = (int) accountType, FirstActivity = firstActivity});
no?